# How to make number picker not cancelable?

Tags: java, android

How to make number picker in Android not cancelable? This my code:

```
public static class NumberPickerDialog extends DialogFragment
{
    private NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener valueChangeListener;
    int min, max, current;
    String title;

    NumberPickerDialog(int min, int max, String title, int current)
    {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
        this.title = title;
        this.current = current;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        final NumberPicker numberPicker = new NumberPicker(getActivity());

        numberPicker.setMinValue(min);
        numberPicker.setMaxValue(max);
        numberPicker.setValue(current);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setCancelable(false); //this doesn't work
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                valueChangeListener.onValueChange(numberPicker,
                        numberPicker.getValue(), numberPicker.getValue());
            }
        });


        builder.setView(numberPicker);
        return builder.create();
    }

    void setValueChangeListener(NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener valueChangeListener)
    {
        this.valueChangeListener = valueChangeListener;
    }
}
```

How to set this dialog always active as long as the user doesn't pick a number? Cancellable options works in other formats but not in number picker. Is problem with component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
new NumberPickerDialog().setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: It works! thanks :D but can You explain why 'builder.setCancelable(false);'  didn't work?

Comment: builder.setCancelable(false); is work but inside DialogFragment. You need to disable cancel DialogFragment